# Changing row-height and column-width in LibreOffice Calc using Python3

Tags: python, libreoffice-calc, uno

I want to write a LibreOffice Calc document from within a Python3 program.  Using pyoo I can do almost everything I want, including formatting and merging cells.  But I cannot adjust row heights and column widths.

I found [Change the column width and row height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43463321/change-the-column-width-and-row-height) very helpful, and have been experimenting with it, but I can't seem to get quite the result I want.  My present test file, based on the answer mentioned above, looks like this:

```
#! /usr/bin/python3

import os, pyoo, time, uno

s = '-'
while s != 'Y':
    s = input("Have you remembered to start Calc? ").upper()

os.popen("soffice --accept=\"socket,host=localhost,port=2002;urp;\" --norestore --nologo --nodefault")
time.sleep(2)
desktop = pyoo.Desktop('localhost', 2002)
doc = desktop.create_spreadsheet()

class ofic:
    sheet_idx = 0
    row_num = 0
    sheet = None

o = ofic()

uno_localContext = uno.getComponentContext()
uno_resolver = uno_localContext.ServiceManager.createInstanceWithContext("com.sun.star.bridge.UnoUrlResolver", uno_localContext )
uno_ctx = uno_resolver.resolve( "uno:socket,host=localhost,port=2002;urp;StarOffice.ComponentContext" )
uno_smgr = uno_ctx.ServiceManager
uno_desktop = uno_smgr.createInstanceWithContext( "com.sun.star.frame.Desktop", uno_ctx)
uno_model = uno_desktop.getCurrentComponent()
uno_controller = uno_model.getCurrentController()
uno_sheet_count = 0

doc.sheets.create("Page {}".format(1), index=o.sheet_idx)
o.sheet = doc.sheets[o.sheet_idx]
o.sheet[0, 0].value = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
o.sheet[1, 1].value = o.sheet_idx

uno_controller.setActiveSheet(uno_model.Sheets.getByIndex(uno_sheet_count))
uno_sheet_count += 1
uno_active_sheet = uno_model.CurrentController.ActiveSheet
uno_columns = uno_active_sheet.getColumns()
uno_column = uno_columns.getByName("B")
uno_column.Width = 1000
```

The main problem with the above is that I have 2 Calc documents on the screen, one of which is created before the Python program gets going; the other is created from Python with a pyoo function.  The first document gets the column width change, and the second receives the text input etc.  I want just the second document, and of course I want the column width change applied to it.

I am sure the answer must be fairly straightforward, but after hours of experimentation I still can't find it.  Could someone point me in the right direction, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code alternates between pyoo and straight Python-UNO, so it's no wonder that it's giving messy results. Pick one or the other. Personally, I use straight Python-UNO and don't see the benefit of adding the extra pyoo library.

> the other is created from Python with a pyoo function

Do you mean this line of code from your question, and is this the "second document" that you want the column change applied to?

```
doc = desktop.create_spreadsheet()
```

If so, then get objects from that document instead of whichever window the desktop happens to have selected.

```
controller = doc.getCurrentController()
sheets = doc.getSheets()
```

Or perhaps you want the other document, the one that didn't get created from Python. In that case, grab a reference to that document before creating the second one.

```
first_doc = uno_desktop.getCurrentComponent()
second_doc = desktop.create_spreadsheet()
controller = first_doc.getCurrentController()
sheets = first_doc.getSheets()
```

If you don't have a reference to the document, you can find it by iterating through the open windows.

```
oComponents = desktop.getComponents()
oDocs = oComponents.createEnumeration()
```

Finally, how to resize a column. The link in your question is for Excel and VBA (both from Microsoft), so I'm not sure why you think that would be relevant. Here is a Python-UNO example of resizing columns.

```
oColumns = oSheet.getColumns()
oColumn = oColumns.getByName("A")
oColumn.Width = 7000
oColumn = oColumns.getByName("B")
oColumn.OptimalWidth = True
```

Comment: I got things working eventually, and my program now does everything I want it to (apart from setting a font).  The code I posted is indeed messy, and @JimK suggests using _either_ pyoo or uno, not both.  I would love to do that, but the problem is that uno is completely opaque to me.  If I type `help(pyoo)` I get a comprehensive list of what pyoo can do and how to do it.  `help(uno)` gives me no idea at all how to do anything within the spreadsheet - say adding a formula, or changing text values.  Where is this information to be found?  Hours of searching have left me still in the dark.

Comment: If you have a working solution that is different from my answer, you should post your own answer, giving the key details of the solution. Either way, it's best to [accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if possible to finish the question. As for where to find information on UNO, the document at https://www.pitonyak.org/oo.php tells how to do both of the things described in your comment. Also, an UNO introspection tool such as MRI is important. If pyoo works then that's fine, although you might get less help than with straight UNO.